# jQuery object equivalence test (deep comparison of content, not identity)

Tags: jquery, compare, equivalence

How can I check that two jQuery objects have equivalent features, that is the same tag names, attributes, values, and text contents?

This question is not a duplicate (content-wise or identity-wise) of any of these:

- [comparing jQuery objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200987/comparing-jquery-objects)
- [How would you compare jQuery objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436966/how-would-you-compare-jquery-objects)
- [How to check for DOM equality with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448291/how-to-check-for-dom-equality-with-jquery)
- [jQuery object equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176962/jquery-object-equality)
- [How do I compare two jQuery objects for identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985932/how-do-i-compare-two-jquery-objects-for-identity)

Most of these apply to selected not synthesized elements, and are answered like so:  compare DOM objects using [0] or .get(0); or after jQuery 1.6 use .is().  By the way, what's up with all that duplication? Anyway those methods don't work for this purpose.  Example:

```
var xx = $('<a>', {href: '#'}).append($('<b>').text('foo'));
var yy = $('<a>', {href: '#'}).append($('<b>').text('foo'));
var zz = $('<a>', {href: '#'}).append($('<b>').text('foobar'));
```

I want a function, call it same_contents(), that would work like this:

```
> same_contents(xx, yy)
true
> same_contents(xx, zz)
false
```

But none of the easy or classic ways do this because they're ultimately comparing identity not contents:

```
> xx == yy
false
> xx == zz
false

> xx[0] == yy[0]
false
> xx[0] == zz[0]
false

> xx.is(yy)
false
> xx.is(zz)
false
```

My purpose for this comparison is to check that a complex object tree was resynthesized accurately using two different methods, via brute force versus via less repetitive function calls.

Answer (score 0):

Generate and compare raw HTML.

```
function same_contents($x, $y) {
    return $x[0].outerHTML == $y[0].outerHTML;
}
```

Then:

```
> same_contents(xx, yy)
true
> same_contents(xx, zz)
false
```

Beware false-negatives for dumb reasons:

```
> same_contents($('<a>', {href: '#', title: 'x'}), $('<a>', {href: '#', title: 'x'}))
true
> same_contents($('<a>', {href: '#', title: 'x'}), $('<a>', {title: 'x', href: '#'}))
false
```

If that's a problem, maybe a [normalizer](https://github.com/TimothyRHuertas/normalizer) would help.

Comment: I wonder if innerHTML would be better as the method is same_contents, which could possibly indicate the desire to only compare the contents, rather than also comparing the top most parents as well.